# Issue with MQTT client connecting to a clustered (3 nodes) NatsIO server

Tags: mqtt, nats.io, hivemq

**NATS Server error:**
node2-c1_1  | [1] 2021/12/13 15:35:15.464884 [INF] Creating MQTT streams/consumers with replicas 1 for account "ADKPM577BVYF7QXUNN6YOFEO4CJUQOPTD3WDEIFNXLW264566UABY3QG"
node2-c1_1  | [1] 2021/12/13 15:35:19.470607 [WRN] 172.18.0.1:60930 - mid:36 - "mqttClient-MQTT_3_1_1-86fbcb3e-3d62-4bef-9ac3-684f54945852" - Readloop processing time: 4.0328908s
node2-c1_1  | [1] 2021/12/13 15:35:19.470719 [ERR] 172.18.0.1:60930 - mid:36 - "mqttClient-MQTT_3_1_1-86fbcb3e-3d62-4bef-9ac3-684f54945852" - unable to connect: create messages stream for account "ADKPM577BVYF7QXUNN6YOFEO4CJUQOPTD3WDEIFNXLW264566UABY3QG": timeout for request type "SC" on "$JS.API.STREAM.CREATE.$MQTT_msgs" (reply="$MQTT.JSA.n50ntl9W.SC.FocGVk4ZKwLQbRYWqJEJUk")
node2-c1_1  | [1] 2021/12/13 15:35:19.470741 [DBG] 172.18.0.1:60930 - mid:36 - "mqttClient-MQTT_3_1_1-86fbcb3e-3d62-4bef-9ac3-684f54945852" - Client connection closed: Protocol Violation

**Client Error:**

CLIENT mqttClient-MQTT_3_1_1-86fbcb3e-3d62-4bef-9ac3-684f54945852: sending CONNECT with Mqtt3Connect: MqttConnect{keepAlive=60, cleanSession=true, simpleAuth=MqttSimpleAuth{username and password}}
PUBLISH: com.hivemq.client.mqtt.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Server closed connection without DISCONNECT.
at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.MqttBlockingClient.connect(MqttBlockingClient.java:91)
at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3BlockingClientView.connect(Mqtt3BlockingClientView.java:69)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.MqttClientExecutor.mqtt3Connect(MqttClientExecutor.java:104)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.AbstractMqttClientExecutor.connectMqtt3Client(AbstractMqttClientExecutor.java:266)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.AbstractMqttClientExecutor.connect(AbstractMqttClientExecutor.java:203)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.MqttClientExecutor.connect(MqttClientExecutor.java:67)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.AbstractMqttClientExecutor.getMqttClientFromCacheOrConnect(AbstractMqttClientExecutor.java:434)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.AbstractMqttClientExecutor.subscribe(AbstractMqttClientExecutor.java:84)
at com.hivemq.cli.mqtt.MqttClientExecutor.subscribe(MqttClientExecutor.java:67)
at com.hivemq.cli.commands.cli.SubscribeCommand.run(SubscribeCommand.java:114)
at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1729)
at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2101)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2068)
at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1935)
at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1864)
at com.hivemq.cli.MqttCLIMain.main(MqttCLIMain.java:73)
PUBLISH: Server closed connection without DISCONNECT.